# Suma de valores conenidos en attributos en un <tr>

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo la duda de que tengo este código:

```
<tr class="ejemplo1" sumaEjemplo="+sumaEjemplo+">
```

Estoy pasando los valores dinámicamente y quiero hacer la suma de todos los   `<tr>` con ese atributo (se van a ir agregando en la página web y ese atributo contiene un valor numérico).

Ejemplo:

```
<tr class="ejemplo1 valorNumerico1="+valorNumerico1+">
```

Aquí tendría que mostrar la suma de todos los valores de los atributos que cacha valorNumerico1.

```
'<td sumaTotal="+sumaTotal+">'+'</td>'
```

¿Cómo lo puedo realizar con jQuery?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, tendrás lo que llevas de código?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer es sencillo con jQuery, tan sólo tendrías que utilizar el [selector de atributo `[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo). Entonces lo que harías sería:

- Declarar una variable para el total e inicializarla a 0
- Seleccionar todos los `tr` que tengan el atributo que quieres `valorNumerico1`
- Añadir el valor de ese atributo al total
- Seleccionar el `td` con atributo `sumaTotal`
- Asignarle el valor de total a ese atributo

Algo como esto (no sé cómo es tu código, así que es algo simple):

```js
// Declarar una variable para el total e inicializarla a 0
let total = 0;

// Seleccionar todos los `tr` que tengan el atributo `valorNumerico1`
$("tr[valorNumerico1]").each(function() {

  // Añadir el valor de ese atributo al total
  total += parseInt($(this).attr("valorNumerico1"));
});

// Seleccionar el `td` con atributo `sumaTotal` y asignarle el valor de total a ese atributo (ya de paso también escribirlo)
$("td[sumaTotal]").attr("sumaTotal", total).text(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Concepto</th>
    <th>Valor</th>
  </tr>
  <tr valorNumerico1="12">
    <td>Auto</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valorNumerico1="10">
    <td>Auto</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valorNumerico2="8">
    <td>Auto2</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL valorNumerico1</td>
    <td sumaTotal=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Alvaro necesito tu aydua en mi ultima pregunta porfa